# Improved lower bound on monotone circuit complexity of perfect matching?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, matching

Razborov proved that every monotone circuit that computes the perfect matching function for bipartite graphs must have at least $n^{\Omega(\log n)}$ gates (he called it "logical permanent"). Has a better lower bound for the same problem been proved since then? (say $2^{n^\epsilon}$?) As far as I remember this problem was open in the mid 1990's.

I am aware that the clique function requires exponential-size monotone circuits and so on, but I am interested in perfect matching specifically.

Answer (score 11):

Eva Tardos proved that the gap is truly exponential by showing that there is a monotone boolean function that has poly size circuits but requires exponential size monotone circuits. Nothing better than super-polynomial is known for matching.

Raz has a result that monotone circuits for matching have linear depth. (Thanks Klauck, for pointing the typo.)

AFAIK, we know nothing better.

Ref: (1) http://www.springerlink.com/index/P25X5838624J0352.pdf

(2) http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~ranraz/publications/Pmatching.ps

Comment: Come on, it's linear depth (and its Raz and Wigderson).

Comment: Come on, Hartmut, the depth lower bound is only $N^{1/2}$ where $N$ is the number of variables (=edges). So far we do not have any $\Omega(N)$ depth lower bound, even for monotone circuits. 

The Perfect Matching is another story.  None of "refined" lower bound arguments can beat Razborov's  lower bound $N^{\Omega(\log N)}$ on the size.